# Predicting past events using fututre data to test model accuracy?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictive-models

I have built a predictive MMA model (logistic regression) using fight data from 2014-2018, now I want to test this model, is it okay if I test it on MMA fights before 2014? What are the things I should be wary of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so, certainly. You should be wary that the data generating process might have changed between your training and your test sample. (And the data that you actually will apply your data to.) But this is the same kind of things you need to be careful of in any case.

If you want to use your model predictively for a later period, it would be more natural to me to fit it using data, say, from 2012 to 2016, then assess it using 2016-2018, finally re-fit the winning model using all your available data and then apply this.